# What is the benefit of the acceptance-function when you have the vote-function?

Tags: discussion, voting, accepted-answer

What is the benefit of the acceptance-function when you have the vote-function?
Currently the acceptance-function belongs to the user asking the question, not the community as the vote-function does.

As I ask in Ask Different Meta
[How does answers to questions that was asked by a deleted user get accepted?](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2674/how-does-answers-to-questions-that-was-asked-by-a-delted-user-get-accepted) there is also an issue with this since if a user is deleted, there will be no acceptance.
Making acceptance-function a function for the community in some form would enable acceptance even if the user is deleted. 
Removing the acceptance-function will also solve this issue.

All solutions have both ups-/down-sides. This is why I raise this question so that we could reflect upon it.

Comment: @JonW not really. The faq does not explain what is the motive behind this system

Comment: @ShadowWizard I dunno the *"...informs others that your issue is resolved."* part of the answer is pretty relevant.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, and for linking to valuable information. I will probably write another question that focuses more on that the acceptance-function still belonging to the user (and not the community) when the user asking the question has been deleted, as the questions/answers mostly focuses on the benefit of the function when the user has not been removed.