# Which answer should I mark as Accepted? Best way or way I actually used?

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer

As the title states, I came across a small but tricky question.

The specific content can be found here: [how to properly handle input dependent async data calls in react component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73884544/how-to-properly-handle-input-dependent-async-data-calls-in-react-component/)

I got one answer which is actually the better way of solving such scenario, but the other answer was more practicable in my specific case because it constituted only a minor refactor. So which one should I mark as the accepted answer? The better way or the actually used way?

Considerations: At first I thought about accepting the actually used way but on the next moment I thought, I better highlight the answer which is more valuable for the community in general. So which one should I choose?

Comment: The answer which is more valuable for the community in general should ideally have more upvotes. Which come *from* the community in general.

Comment: See “Which answer should I accept?” in https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/196432

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What answer should one accept when they both answer different aspects of the question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/376325/282094),  https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/343472/282094 https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333993/282094 https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/327950/282094 https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/269619/282094 - this exact question and various flavors of it has been asked many times before. Voting and accepting reflect different aspects of what is conveyed, accepting is what helped the asker the most; you can vote on other helpful answers too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [help article on accepting an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer):

> Accepting an answer is not meant to be a definitive and final statement indicating that the question has now been answered perfectly. It simply means that the author received an answer that worked for them personally.

But, really, it's absolutely up to you which answer you choose to accept. The accepted answer checkmark is *meant* to indicate that a particular answer helped the question author the most. What "helped" means is entirely up to you. Did that more broadly-valuable answer give you insight in some way, even if you decided to choose the other solution? Maybe consider accepting that one. Or don't! You have no obligation to accept either if you don't want to.

As VLAZ [mentioned in a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382433/which-answer-sould-i-mark-as-accepted-best-way-or-way-i-actually-used#comment1275559_382433), votes from the community are really the most driving way we have of moderating good content and granting it higher or lower visibility (i.e. good answers rise to the top, less-useful answers float to the bottom). The accepted answer checkmark [no longer pins the answer to the top of the answers list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/411352/11171084) over on Stack Overflow, so you're not exerting any visibility power with your choice of accepted answer.